# My question does not show up in the tag's newest questions list.

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, new-questions

I recently posted this question: [Error while using onActivityResults() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15173528/2060383).

Now when I click on the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag and try to see my question, it does not show up. Moreover when I click on the Question button it is showing the questions about 20 minutes before. The question queue seems to have stopped being refreshed on the new questions.

Is this any kind of bug?

Comment: Looks like same thing on meta site, i can't see my question in the list even after 4 minutes from posting question.

Comment: Yeah, same behaviour here. Fairly recent questions don't show up, though the live-refresh does seem to work. An issue with the site's caching perhaps?

Comment: Could you check again? Now your Android question does seem to show up. The issue seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: @Bart, thanks for response, i checked it again, but still it is not showing my question in Android tag list, however, my question has been answered and i found the proper result too.

Comment: Talking to this problem on SO & MSO site's recent question list, this has happened in last jun-july 2012 month too. Still i remember it was two times

Comment: @Bart, ok, now it is showing recent question list properly. **Status : Completed** :)

Comment: Good. These are most often temporary glitches that tend to get fixed pretty rapidly.

Comment: There was some outage on other sites, too. Maybe some short-term problem with the servers, some usually cached info might have gotten lost and it'll take a while for it to rebuild :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little late to the party, but one of our services had a bit of an outage around the time this was happening.

It's long since been fixed.

Comment: it happened to me today! did they change something else?

Comment: It happened to me today and yesterday.....