# Question list on Stack Overflow is not showing new question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, meta, newest-questions

On Stack Overflow the last question was asked approx 1 hour ago. It is not getting updated. Since the volume of the users are a lot, I can't believe that nobody has asked question since last 1 hour. I think there is some problem.

Please look into it.

Edit : Now it is showing lastest question as 30 mins ago. But on the other hand same kind of problem is started on meta site. The active tab is not getting refresh with current discussing question.

Comment: Just refresh your page 1 or 2 times. [There](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17607378/1369235) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607379/correlate-query-not-working) [lots of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607360/what-wrong-when-i-want-to-edit-the-extjs-grid-the-record-will-delete-not-edit) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607358/what-is-the-best-way-to-execute-a-command-soon-as-usb-drive-is-mounted-at-media) [coming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607335) [right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606897) [now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607416).

Comment: Something weird is up with `/questions`, for sure.  Clearing cache and/or visiting the root domain seems to help?

Comment: Now the list is updated to latest question about 21 mins ago. but still I am sure it is not showing 1 min ago's question

Comment: @Vigbyor - Ironic. Now your question is not showing me on [Meta's Active page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions doesn't seem to update (28 minutes of inactivity).

Comment: @hims056,  yes I felt same on meta.

Comment: @hims056 That might be a (serious) problem. People won't be seeing this complaint. But I'm sure people will find a way to ping the mods.

Comment: Related or duplicate : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169788/227860

Comment: Same here I didn't see any new question from last 1 hour :(

Comment: Eeeek! [SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) isn't showing *any* questions on [`/questions`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions)!

Comment: check now I got the updated list right now.

Comment: Wait. The problem seems to be recurring every now and then, showing old posts (~2 hours for me) on one reload and the newest ones on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating via Firefox Web Console, it seems the request to fetch the questions for the main page of most sites returned a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Whilst I was writing this, the problem seems to have been resolved (I was going to provide a nice screenshot and everything, but the devs were too quick!)

Comment: It is currently on & off again, very difficult to reproduce at this stage. Hopefully I can catch it again and get that screenshot